# Software-level volume control for OSX?

Tags: audio, sound-volume

For logistical reasons, my current sound configuration is the following.

```
          USB-C            3.5mm
Macbook ————————➜ Monitor ———————➜ Speaker
```

While this configuration works well, there's no way to change the volume of the computer without changing the physical dials of the speaker.

[image: The selected device has no output controls]

Is there any way to set the volume by "software" instead of using the outputs controls?

Comment: There’s no software that allows you to control external audio devices.  HDMI and DisplayPort have audio signals embedded, but no control signals to manage the end device.

Answer (score 1):

I use an app called [Sound Control](https://staticz.com/soundcontrol/), which allows you to configure sound settings in all sorts of ways, including individually for each app.

I use it to provide software volume for my Aggregate Output device, which is a Dell Soundbar and my Thunderbolt Display together as one.

It may work for your setup.